# Background based on element's position

Tags: html, css

I would like to use tranparency to see a background image.

I'm using for html :

```
body{
    background-image:url("000000000.jpg");
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Here 0 is **body**, 1 is a **div** above body, 2 is another **div** above the first div.

```
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000111111111110000000
0000000111111222110000000
0000000111111222110000000
0000000111111111110000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
```

I would like to use tranparency to see the background when several div are on top of each other.

My problem is for the "2", i can still see the 1 in transparency (And if 1 and 2 contain text it's unreadable).

How can I avoid that in css?

```css
body{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
}
#div1{
    border:1px solid #fff;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
#div2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="div1">111111111111111111111111111 <br>111111111111111111111111111
<br>111111111111111111111111111
<br>111111111111111111111111111
<br>111111111111111111111111111
<br>111111111111111111111111111</div>
  <div id="div2">22222<br>22222</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where's your minimal working example?

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible with just html and css, this will have to be done in js. In addition, you'll never get transparency through multiple elements to the back of stacking order. You'll need to fake it with js.

Comment: I think i saw that before on a moveable "window". It just take the same background as "html" but instead of starting at coordinates 0,0 it will just adapt to the position of the window and then find the correct coordinates to match perfectly with the other background.

Comment: Sir Zimmerman. welcome to StackOverflow! I am curious, are your recent win of Nobel Prize and your interest in coding related in any way? Or is it just a coincidence? What you are trying to achieve [is possible](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/). However, your request is on the borderline of being **too broad**.

Comment: I won a Nobel ? I had no idea, i've been very busy trying to learn new things.